# Does the Recipients - Edit options - location type for CiviMail override the default bulk email settings?

Tags: civimail, documentation

I am updating the user guide and don't have access to a 4.6 or 4.7 site where email is working, so I would appreciate an answer to the following rather than "test it yourself" (which otherwise would be a perfectly valid answer). I have read https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15361 but I am still not sure what will happen for some of these contacts.

Contact A has the following email addresses:

- Home - set as primary
- Work
- Other - set as bulk emailing

Contact B has:

- Home
- Work - set as primary
- Other - set as bulk emailing

Contact C has:

- Home
- Work - set as primary
- Other

Contact D has:

- Home - set as primary
- Work - set as bulk emailing
- Other

If under "edit options" I set the location type to Work and I select "Only send to email addresses assigned to the specified location" who will get the email?

Who gets it if I set the location type to Work and I select "Exclude email addresses assigned to the specified location"